# WPF: Adorner not receiving any keyboard events

Tags: wpf, adorner

I have an Adorner and I want that Adorner to be able to receive keyboard events, but I'm having problems with those whole focus stuff. Can somebody please tell, what has to be done to make an adorner able to receive keyboard events? Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
adorner.Focusable=true;
Keyboard.Focus(adorner);
```